# Python multiprocessing slowed down even in mono-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

I want to run the same code in parallel using multiprocess.

My process code run in 8 minutes alone. In 10 minutes when using the "force mono-thread" thing. But when I run 24 of them in parallel, each instance takes approximately 1 hour.

Before, when each process spanned threads furiously like a mad man, I had context switches of 1.6M. 
I then used the following env. variables to force Numpy to only use one thread per process:

```python
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = '1'
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = '1'
os.environ["MKL_THREADING_LAYER"] = "sequential"  # Better than setting MKL_NUM_THREADS=1 (source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528380)
```

Even after that, my problem remains. I have runtime around 1 hour per process. 
Using glances, apart from the CPU that is used at 95-100% (red in glances) the rest is green, memory, bandwith, even context switches is back to normal at around 5K.

Do you have an idea of why this happens? I don't get why this is 6 times slower in parallel when no obvious indicator pop up in glances

Here is in attachement a screen capture of glances[image: glances output]

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: The code is difficult to compress in a "minimum example". The main code is a python process that does complex calculations (an instrumental simulator). 

The Pool is a home made pool that uses multiprocessing.Process, then check if the process is still alive using p.is_alive(), then launch a new process if one ended. Why is that? Because multiprocessing.Pool doesn't allow me to handle memory on top of CPUs and sometimes I'm not limited by number of CPU but by RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific problem, I've found the answer. It seems that it's due to my hardware rather than the code.

The code runs fine in another server of 16 CPUs. When using 15 of them, I get a time of 8 minutes, which was exactly what I was looking for.

I think something in the old server makes it slow for multiprocesses.

Old server where it doesn't work:

```
processor   : 23
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 8
model name  : Six-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 8439 SE
stepping    : 0
cpu MHz     : 2800.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 3
siblings    : 6
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 29
initial apicid  : 29
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
bugs        : tlb_mmatch fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg amd_e400 spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 5600.33
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate
```

New server where it works:

```
processor   : 15
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 2599.998
cache size  : 16384 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 7
cpu cores   : 8
apicid      : 15
initial apicid  : 15
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat xsaveopt
bogomips    : 5199.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: You should really either insert the specs of the "old hardware" or just delete your question. Right now it is completely useless to anyone (including you). Adding hardware&software specs somebody could find out why multiprocessing performed badly and this question could be changed to something useful (including for you).

Comment: Agreed, I was editing my comment but forgot to send it before going to lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Without a "minimal code example", it is indeed difficult to answer, so instead of a straight answer, I'll provide some code. I've experimented with:

```
import os
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
import numpy as np
import time
def tns(): return time.time_ns() / 1e9

def nps(vec, its=100): 
    return min(np.linalg.norm(vec - np.random.randn(len(vec))) for _ in range(its))

start = tns()
s = nps(np.random.randn(100_000))
end = tns()
print("{} took {}".format(s, end - start))
```

On my machine, setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` yields a ~2.5 times speed-up. The explanation I received from #numpy on freenode was that my code is memory-bound and thus multi-threading won't help.